# static_assert that a member variable is marked as 'static' in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, type-traits

I've been playing around with templates and would like to enforce that a template type given to a function has a particular static member. Unfortunately, there is no `std::is_static` type trait.

A rough example of how I would use it (or an alternative):

```
template<typename T>
void SomeFunc(T& obj)
{
    static_assert(std::is_static_v<decltype(T::someVariable)>, "someVariable must be static");
}
```

Are there any ways to achieve this kind of behaviour? I could just write

```
template<typename T>
void SomeFunc(T& obj)
{
    // must be static
    T::someVariable;
}
```

But this wouldn't be anywhere near as nice or informative as a `static_assert` with a decent message. This is just a syntax error of sorts :(

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, the best you can get here is a syntax error. The compiler is trying to resolve `T::someVariable`. If it cannot, of course it's a compiler error. There's no way around this. If you want to check if `T::someVariable` is a static member or a function, use `type_traits` header.

Comment: That was my point - I couldn't figure out how to use type_traits to solve the problem :) But max66's answer seems to cover that.

Comment: @HateDread - not sure the nakiya's objection but I've improved my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, you're looking for `std::is_member_pointer` (or the opposite of the value of `std::is_member_pointer`).

An example (also C++11 and C++14 compliant)

```
#include <type_traits>

struct foo
 { int value; };

struct bar
 { static int value; };

int main()
 {
   static_assert(
      true == std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&foo::value)>::value, "!");
   static_assert(
      false == std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&bar::value)>::value, "!!");
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

Not sure to understand the nakiya's objection but ... in the following example I've developed a type traits (`hasSomeValueStatic`) that set `value` to `true` if the template argument has a `someValue` static member and `false` otherwhise (if `someValue` isn't `static` of there isn't `someValue`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo
 { int someValue; };

struct bar
 { static int someValue; };

template <typename, typename = int>
struct hasSomeValueStatic : std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T>
struct hasSomeValueStatic<T, decltype(T::someValue, 0)>
      : std::integral_constant<bool,
           ! std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&T::someValue)>::value>
 { };

int main()
 {
   std::cout << hasSomeValueStatic<foo>::value << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << hasSomeValueStatic<bar>::value << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << hasSomeValueStatic<int>::value << std::endl; // print 0
 }
```

Comment: He/She wants to get a "Error message" instead of a compiler error when he/she tries to access a non-existing `T::someVariable`.

Comment: @nakiya - not sure to understand your objection but... answer modified.

Comment: Thanks max66, this is exactly what I was after! I'm not too worried about whether it exists, since there are earlier checks for that (not mentioned because I figured they weren't relevant to this very specific issue). Are there any limitations or gotchas of `std::is_member_pointer` that I should be worried about?

Comment: @HateDread - about `std::is_member_pointer`, take in count that respond `true` when `T::someValue` is a static variable **and** when is a static function (method); if you want select only variables, give a look at `std::is_member_object_pointer`; anyway, give a look at the [page in cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_pointer)